# function or script to reverse Byte Order oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a script in PL/SQL to convert the byte order of a Hexadecimal number in pairs

ex. `A1B2C3D4` should become `D4C3B2A1`

Could you please help me which function or what script should I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UTL_RAW` package has a handy [`REVERSE` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71412):

```
select utl_raw.reverse('A1B2C3D4') from dual;

UTL_RAW.REVERSE('A1B2C3D4')
---------------------------
D4C3B2A1
```

That gives you a `RAW` value, and I'm doing an implicit conversion from string to `RAW` in that example as I don't know what data type you're starting with.

You can expand this to convert explicitly from a `VARCHAR2` with the [`HEXTORAW` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions073.htm):

```
select utl_raw.reverse(hextoraw('A1B2C3D4')) from dual;

UTL_RAW.REVERSE(HEXTORAW('A1B2C3D4'))
-------------------------------------
D4C3B2A1
```

and back to `VARCHAR2` with the [`RAWTOHEX` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions143.htm):

```
select rawtohex(utl_raw.reverse(hextoraw('A1B2C3D4'))) from dual;

RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.REVERSE(HEXTORAW('A1B2C3D4')))
-----------------------------------------------
D4C3B2A1
```

... depending on exactly what you need back.

Comment: thanks for your help..actually I am using varchar2 data type and I want to keep the same datatype after the conversion

Comment: @yogi - the final version ends up as a `varchar2`; [ROWTOHEX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions143.htm) returns that data type.